# Why would background-attachment:scroll not work?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned DIV with overflow auto. When I scroll down, the background clearly looks fixed, even though the default for everything on my site is scroll. It still had this behavior when I tried both ways of defining the background on the DIV:

`background-attachment: scroll;` 
`background: url() repeat top center scroll #000`

Extremely lost. Thought it might be because it was absolutely positioned DIV but even when I undid that, it still failed. Problem in FF, Safari, Chrome, and IE.

UPDATE:
Here is the latest code I tried.. on the actual site the CSS is in a file that I point to in a head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        .template-body {
          background-attachment:scroll;
          background-color:#151515;
          background-image:url("http://www.fake.com/images/2183ba03681e577511e6589e554b7a86.jpg");
          background-position:center top;
          background-repeat:repeat;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="template-body" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 332px; right: 0px; top: 93px; bottom: 0px; width: 1094px; z-index: 1; visibility: visible; display: block; background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21); height: 696px;">

          <div>
            Here lies all the content that makes .template-body scroll
          </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Attempting to set heights in firebug on the inner/content DIV did not help in any way.

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't have a URL in your `url()`?

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you don't know what's broken about your code, don't chop bits out of it before you post a question about it ;) Who knows what other CSS you already removed which might affect  your situation

Comment: Sorry Gareth, just posted the pseudo code real quick late at office. The url is definitely filled properly. I can't quite provide a link since it's a project in development using jquery ui layout on top of it all.

Comment: try my updated answer, i think its what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background of the div remains fixed, as the div is not moving in any way. It's just the content of the div that is scrolled.

Put the background image on the content of the div instead. You can wrap the content in another div if needed.

#### Edit:

Put the background image on the inner div, so that it follows the content that is scrolling. To make the background fill the outer div even if the content is smaller, put the same background on the outer div.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dLMux/)

Comment: There is a div with the background and scrollbar, and the inside div is what has enough content on the site to make the outer div scroll.

Comment: To clarify, I thought that since the inner div had enough content for the scrollbar to appear, that the outer div would behave as though it is what has the content since it's the parent node. But clearly your logic is trumping that.

Comment: @Dave Stein: It is the outer div that gets the scrollbar, but that doesn't make it's background follow the content when it's scrolled. It doesn't work like when you set the background on the body and it scrolls, that is a special case and it's handled differently.

Comment: @Dave Stein: I added an example above of how to set the background on the scrolling content.

Comment: Ah I see. So I only see a scrollbar when I can't see the entire inner div, so when I scroll down all the way I still won't see any of the outerdiv, therefore there's no "fixed" look. Then obviously when there's no scrollbar, everything lines up perfect since both divs start in the same top and left. Thanks.

Comment: I think the explainantion is wrong ("as the div is not moving"), because then background-attachment would not have any meaning. When you scroll a div, its viewport ist scrolling (scrollTop, scrollLeft) - background-attachment:scroll should definitly move its background as well.

Comment: @Gerfried: Yes, the viewport is scrolling, but the element isn't. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) about ´scroll´ says: _"This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the element itself and does not scroll with its contents."_

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnnue/

(basically what Guffa was saying)

i added a `.bg-image` div to the template div, and positioned it below the content using z-index. i made the width thinner to better ese the scrolling.

<strike>a link would be helpful. what i interpret to be your code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/pvaEM/4/</strike>

and the bg image is scrolling.  can you reproduce the problem on that fiddle?

Comment: That's because the div doesn't have a fixed size, so the overflow style doesn't make it's content scroll. It's the body of the document that is scrolling.

Comment: Set a height on the div, and the background stays fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/pvaEM/18/

Comment: good catch! I'll wait to see if Dave will put up some code and come up with a solution.

Comment: I see it clearly now and the background is definitely scrolling correctly in your example. The odd thing I'm seeing though is that the bg_image div is not going height 100% as it usually would since it's absolute inside an absolute DIV.

Comment: its going to 100% of `.template-body`, if you give `.bg_image` the same dimensions as your bg image file, then it will keep scrolling below.

Comment: I tried your solution and ran into same issue. Since parent div has a defined width and height, and overflow auto, the aboslute background div is not filling 100%, just the defined width and height. The second I remove overflow auto, the background goes back to expanding all the way, but obviously no scrollbar appears.

Comment: If I give dimensions to .bg_image it wouldn't scroll because at that point the div is cut off inside the parent that is much wider.... I have to refresh this page more cause I'm not getting e-mails for some reason, just saw your response after I responded again.

Comment: i think the problem might be in how you are structuring this.  maybe the background image should be elsewhere, like in the body.  since i'm not sure of what your desired effect is, it is hard to guess what teh best solution would be. in the example, if you give the `.bg_image` div a height of 3000px, it will fillup 3000px vertically without stretching the parent div

Comment: Without being too specific, sometimes it will be on the body tag and there won't be an issue. For a second I thought that cheating with 9999px on the .bg_image would work and I was happy, but I'm not in control of the height so it's foreseeable that it could be taller ( and I found some examples where it will be ). Oh the woes of user generated content.

Comment: ah, that changes things.  maybe you can write som js that measures the image coming in and gives the bg_image div the correponding height?

Comment: Yeah that thought definitely crossed my mind after our last exchange. Maybe some epiphany will hit me before I have to do that solution - although I'm pretty sure between me and you we've tried every combination of divs and css without the help of JS.

Comment: this might help you: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm

Comment: Went with guffa's solution :) Yours was nearly identical except I think the height was set in the wrong place at first.